# Backup slowness after changing the SAN switch

Tags: backup, storage, switch, storage-area-network, database-backup

We have a netbackup environment

Recently we changed the connectivity of two of our sql servers(cluster servers) from one SAN switch(MDS 9509) to another (MDS 9513) followed by which we are experiencing longer backup times for these servers.

The storage for these servers are provisioned from Symmetrix VMAX.

Can anyone please help us to troubleshoot this.?????

Comment: Do you have any tools for looking at bandwidth utilization?  ANy differences in configuration?  Jumbo Frames? etc

Comment: No we dont have any tools for that ,we tried comparing the configuration and it seems to be the same , all other servers connected to the new switch is working fine @jmoyer8

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend seeing whether you can find clues about the source of the problem in the servers' scsi logs. Since all the other servers continue to work fine, see if there's a difference between the disk configs of those servers and these ones. Maybe the old switches' configurations were masking a problem with your multipath setup or driver levels.

At the switch level, check whether there are errors on the SAN or server ports. If there are, that might indicate a damaged wire, sfp, or hba port. Next, check that the negotiated speed is the same as before. If one port is hard-coded too low, that could cause this.